# PHP: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

I want to select the best find result. I'm getting an error: 
here I am shown HTML form action and DB connection in the file below here please check it. and error msg also mention this section. i am using php 7.2 than some getting problem

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable in D:\xammp\htdocs\search\index.php on line 64

**Warning:  Use of undefined constant city_id - assumed 'city_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in D:\xammp\htdocs\search\index.php on line 37**

help me...error msg.

PHP:

```php
<?php
$i = 1;
if (count($searchdata) > 0) {
    foreach ($searchdata as $places) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>' . $i . '</th>';
        echo '<td>' . $places['city'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $places['visiting_place'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $places['history'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo '<td colspan="4">No Search Result Found.</td>';
}
?>
```

I'm using PHP like:

```php
<?php
$searchdata = [];
$keyword = '';
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    $searchdata = $model->getVisitinPlaceData($city, $keyword);
}
?>
```

**db connection and tabel data fetching**

```
<?php 
class Db {
    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'test';
    private $conn;
    public function __construct() { 
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database); 
        if(!$this->conn) {
            echo 'Database not connected';
        }
    }
    public function getTouristCity(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tourist_city WHERE is_enabled = '1'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        return $result;
    }
    public function getVisitingPlaces(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM visiting_places WHERE is_enabled = '1'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        return $result;
    }
    public function getVisitinPlaceData($cityid, $keyword){
        $sWhere = '';
        $where = array();
        if($cityid > 0) {
            $where[] = 'V.city_id = '.$cityid.' AND V.is_enabled = "1"';
        }

        if($keyword != '') {
            $keyword = trim($keyword);
            $where[] = "( V.visiting_place LIKE '%$keyword%' OR  V.history LIKE '%$keyword%'  OR  C.city LIKE '%$keyword%' )";
        }
        $sWhere     = implode(' AND ', $where);
        if($sWhere) {
            $sWhere = 'WHERE '.$sWhere;
        } 
        if(($cityid > 0) || ($keyword != '')) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM visiting_places AS V JOIN tourist_city AS C ON C.city_id = V.city_id $sWhere ";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**html form action**

```
<form action="" method="post" > 

            <div class="col-sm-3"> 

                <select name="city" class="form-control">

                <option value="0">Select City</option>
                <?php foreach($turistCity as $city) {
                    $checked = ($_POST['city'] == $city[city_id])? 'selected' : '';
                    echo '<option value="'.$city[city_id].'" '.$checked.'>'.$city[city].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"> 
             <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Keword" value="<?php echo $keyword;?>" class="form-control"> 
            </div>

            <button name="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging? What did `var_dump($searchdata);` show?

Comment: try to check with if(!empty($searchdata)) {

Comment: yes I am using PHP like $searchdata = [];
 $keyword = '';
if (isset($_POST['search']))  {
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
 
 
 $searchdata = $model->getVisitinPlaceData($city, $keyword);
}
 
?>

Comment: what type data does `$model->getVisitinPlaceData($city, $keyword);` return?

Comment: If `foreach` works, the class implements `Iterable` but not `Countable`.

Comment: remove this $searchdata = []; and var_dump($searchdata) after execution

Comment: You are returning a mysqli_result out of your method, and that implements the Traversable interface only. Simply call fetch_all and return the result of that instead, so that you have a normal _array_ at the point where you want to count the elements. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply wrap it in a conditional that checks if it is countable, so..

```
// PHP >= 7.3
if(is_countable($searchdata)) {
    // Do something
}

// PHP >= 7.1
if(is_iterable($searchdata)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Note: You should never, ever assume anything is true unless you explicitly define it as such. `count($something)` implies an expectation that it is indeed an array or something you can count. If this is not always the case, and so you much check it before proceeding.

**EDIT**: Use `is_iterable()` for PHP >= 7.1 or `is_countable()` for >= 7.3 in this scenario. Snippet above updated

Comment: than geting errorr .Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_countable() in D:\xammp\htdocs\search\index.php:64 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xammp\htdocs\search\index.php on line 64

Comment: @AmitabhKr Apologies, `is_countable()` is a 7.3 thing, I misread the question. You should be able to use `is_iterable()` to the same effect, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.3 gave error with:
// If the requested page doesn't exist.
if ( $elements['page'] > count( $elements['pages'] ) ) {

Changed it to:
if(is_countable($elements['page'])) {

That fixed it!

Comment: This is better served as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Can you explain that further? The given code does not contain `$elements`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot wrap all the clause where you use count, or you are using several counts, you only need to create empty arrays of the uncountable, just add before your actual code.

```
if(!is_countable($your_array))$your_array = Array();
```