# local.ERROR: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel

```
<script>

    var tableData = [];
    function addRowToTable() {
        var rowData = {
            categoryName: $("#category option:selected").text(),
            itemName: $("#items option:selected").text(),
            costPrice: parseFloat($("#items option:selected").data('cost-price')) || 0,
            netAmount: parseFloat($("#amount").val()) || 0,
            qty: 1
        };

        tableData.push(rowData);

        var newRow = "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + tableData.length + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + rowData.categoryName + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + rowData.itemName + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + rowData.costPrice.toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
            "<td>0</td>" +
            "<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.qty + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + rowData.netAmount.toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
            "<td><button onclick='removeRow(" + (tableData.length - 1) + ")'>Remove</button></td>" +
            "</tr>";

        $("#itemTableBody").append(newRow);

        updateCalculations();
    }

    function removeRow(index) {
        tableData.splice(index, 1);
        updateTable();
        updateCalculations();
    }

    function updateTable() {
        $("#itemTableBody").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
            var rowData = tableData[i];
            var newRow = "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + rowData.categoryName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + rowData.itemName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + rowData.costPrice.toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
                "<td>0</td>" +
                "<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.qty + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + rowData.netAmount.toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
                "<td><button onclick='removeRow(" + i + ")'>Remove</button></td>" +
                "</tr>";

            $("#itemTableBody").append(newRow);
        }
    }

    function submitForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var categoryName = $("#category option:selected").text();
        var itemName = $("#items option:selected").text();
        var costPrice = parseFloat($("#items option:selected").data('cost-price')) || 0;
        var netAmount = parseFloat($("#amount").val()) || 0;
        var existingRow = findExistingRow(itemName);

        if (existingRow) {
            var currentQty = parseFloat(existingRow.find("td:eq(5)").text()) || 0;
            var newQty = currentQty + 1;

            existingRow.find("td:eq(5)").text(newQty);
            existingRow.find("td:eq(6)").text((costPrice * newQty).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            var rowId = Date.now();
            var newRow = "<tr id='row_" + rowId + "'>" +
                "<td>1</td>" +
                "<td>" + categoryName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + itemName + "</td>" +
                "<td contenteditable='true' id='mrp' style='border: 3px solid gray'>" + costPrice + "</td>" +
                "<td>0</td>" +
                "<td contenteditable='true' style='border: 3px solid gray'>1</td>" +
                "<td>" + costPrice + "</td>" +
                "<td><button style='background: #fff;color: #1f224f;font-size: 14px;border: 0px;margin-top: 15px;margin-left: 40%;' onclick='removeRow(" + rowId + ")'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button></td>" +
                "</tr>";

            $("tbody").append(newRow);
        }

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('recognitionForm1'));
        console.log(formData[0]);
        // Include additional data if needed
        formData.append('item_id', $("#items").val());
        formData.append('item_name', $("#items option:selected").text());
        formData.append('net_amount', netAmount);
        formData.append('sale_price', parseFloat($("#items option:selected").data('cost-price')) || 0);
        formData.append('qty', parseFloat(existingRow.find("td:eq(5)").text()) || 0);
        formData.append('pay_method', $("#paymentMode").val());

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('admin-recognition-save') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            },
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
                showCustomToast(response.message, 'success');
                clearFormFields();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 2000);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                showCustomToast('Error saving data. Please try again.', 'error');
            }
        });

        updateCalculations();
    }

    function clearFormFields() {
        $("#retailerName").val("");
        $("#mobileNumber").val("");
        $("#address").val("");
        $("#emailAddress").val("");
        $("#paymentMode").val("cash");
        $("#category").val("");
        $("#subCategory").val("");
        $("#childCategory").val("");
        $("#items").val("");
    }

    function findExistingRow(itemName) {
        var existingRow = null;

        $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
            var existingItemName = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
            if (existingItemName === itemName) {
                existingRow = $(this);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return existingRow;
    }

    function updateCalculations() {
        var subTotal = 0;
        var netAmount = 0;

        $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
            var qty = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(5)").text()) || 0;
            var costPrice = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text()) || 0;
            var mrp = parseFloat($(this).find("td#mrp").text()) || 0;


            subTotal += costPrice * qty;
            netAmount += mrp * qty;
        });

        $("#subTotal").val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
        $("#amount").val(netAmount.toFixed(2));
        $("#receiveAmount").val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
    }

    function removeRow(rowId) {
        $("#row_" + rowId).remove();
        updateCalculations();
        showCustomToast("✓ Data deleted successfully!", "success");
    }

    function showCustomToast(message, type) {
        var toast = $("#customToast");


        toast.text(message);
        toast.removeClass("error-toast").removeClass("success-toast");

        if (type === "success") {
            toast.addClass("success-toast");
        } else if (type === "error") {
            toast.addClass("error-toast");
        }

        toast.slideDown(300, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                toast.slideUp(300);
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here first I store multiple data into table and after that I want to post it into Database but this error is showing.
**[2023-11-21 12:48:11] local.ERROR: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable at C:\xampp\htdocs\coral\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\InventoryController.php:826)**

here is my controller code:

```
public function saveRecognition(Request $request)
{
    $referenceNumber = "RO-" . str_pad(mt_rand(0, 999), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Get the array of category names, item names, cost prices, and net amounts
    $categoryNames = $request->input('categoryName');
    $itemNames = $request->input('itemName');
    $costPrices = $request->input('costPrice');
    $netAmounts = $request->input('netAmount');

    // Loop through each row data
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($categoryNames); $i++) {
        // Create a new recognition info record for each row
        $recognitionInfo = new InvRecognitionInfo();
        $recognitionInfo->item_id = $request->input('item_id');
        $recognitionInfo->qty = $request->input('qty');
        $recognitionInfo->stock_status = 1;
        $recognitionInfo->total_cost = $netAmounts[$i];
        $recognitionInfo->item_name = $itemNames[$i];
        $recognitionInfo->recognition_no = $referenceNumber;
        $recognitionInfo->created_at = now();
        $recognitionInfo->updated_at = now();
        $recognitionInfo->active_status = 1;

        $recognitionInfo->save();

        // Create a new recognition detail record for each row
        $recognitionDetail = new InvRecognitionDetail();
        $recognitionDetail->item_id = $request->input('item_id');
        $recognitionDetail->item_name = $itemNames[$i];
        $recognitionDetail->sale_price = $costPrices[$i];
        $recognitionDetail->qty = $request->input('qty');
        $recognitionDetail->pay_method = $request->input('pay_method');
        $recognitionDetail->recognition_no = $referenceNumber;
        $recognitionDetail->created_at = now();
        $recognitionDetail->updated_at = now();
        $recognitionDetail->active_status = 1;

        $recognitionDetail->save();
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Data saved successfully!']);
}
```

Solve this error. I can't understand the error.

Comment: It would really help to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Anyway just looking at the error: are you sure `$categoryNames` is an array?

Comment: @tobifasc No Not in an array

Comment: Do either one help you? [refer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020833/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable-in-lar) and [refer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608157/php-warning-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-c)

Comment: As the error says: the paramater for [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) must be an array or an object that implements Countable